# Real world advantage of using Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I understand the usage of BeanFactoryPostProcessor where we can modify metadata of bean definitions by writing our custom class which implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor. But I fail to understand Why or What is the advantage of changing metadata value via BeanFactoryPostProcessor when I can simple change it in the spring xml itself.

Answer (score 1):

- Lets take `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer BeanFactoryPostProcessor` as an example which spring itself uses. It allows the following bean definition modified before it becomes the concrete bean definition (.ie `${jdbc.url}` replaced with the correct value )

```
   <bean id="dataSource">
     <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
   </bean>
```

- Without it, you have to have many different bean definitions for each environment like `test`, `stage`, `production` and different profiles to activate them. And then you have security issue because you have to store the production database url in the definition.
- This is just one simple example, there are so many `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` implementations spring itself uses. Check them through

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify spring config in libraries you pull in and have no control over :)